# Empty output when reproducing Chinese coreference results on Conll-2012 using CoreNLP Neural System

Tags: stanford-nlp

Following the instructions on this page https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html#running-on-conll-2012, Here's my code when I tried to reproduce Chinese coreference results on Conll-2012:

```
public class TestCoref {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties(args);

    props.setProperty("props", "edu/stanford/nlp/coref/properties/neural-chinese-conll.properties");

    props.setProperty("coref.data", "path-to/data/conll-2012");

    props.setProperty("coref.conllOutputPath", "path-to-output/conll-results");

    props.setProperty("coref.scorer", "path-to/reference-coreference-scorers/v8.01/scorer.pl");


    CorefSystem coref = new CorefSystem(props);


    coref.runOnConll(props);

}
```

}

As output, I got 3 files like these:

"date-time.coref.predicted.txt

date-time.coref.gold.txt

date-time.predicted.txt"

but all of them are EMPTY!

I got my "conll-2012" data as follows:

First I downloaded train/dev/test-key data from this page http://conll.cemantix.org/2012/data.html, as well as the ontonote-release-5.0 from LDC. Then I ran the script skeleton2conll.sh provided with the official conll 2012 data which produced _conll files.

the model I used is downloaded here http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-chinese-corenlp-models-current.jar

When I tried to find the problem, I noticed that there exists a function "annotate" in the class CorefSystem which seems to do the real job, but it is not used at all. https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/coref/CorefSystem.java

I wonder if there is a bug in runOnConll function which doesn't read an annotate anything, or how could I reproduce the coreference results?

PS:

I especially want to produce some results on conversational data like "tc" and "bc" in conll-2012. I find that using the coreference API, I can only parse textual data. Is there any other way to use Neural Coref System on conversational data (where different speakers should be indicated) apart from running on Conll-2012?

thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

As a start, why don't you run this command from the command line:

```
java -Xmx10g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.9.1.jar:stanford-chine-corenlp-models-3.9.1.jar:* edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefSystem -props edu/stanford/nlp/coref/properties/neural-chinese-conll.properties -coref.data <path-to-conll-data> -coref.conllOutputPath <where-to-save-system-output> -coref.scorer <path-to-scoring-script>
```

Comment: I also tried this command line, and it gives the same empty result files

Comment: I don't know if this affects things, but there is a typo in my command, it should have: "stanford-corenlp-3.9.1-models-chinese.jar" in it.  Could you post in your question the output when you run that command?  And could you post the full command you are running?  It's possible you don't have the Chinese models jar in your CLASSPATH so it's not loading the correct coreference models.